# Implementing DELETE endpoint with my Restful API

Tags: node.js, rest, api, mongoose

```
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res){

    var userID = req.params.id;

    user.remove({

        userID

    }, function(err, users) {

        if(err) {
            res.status(404).send({
                message: "Invalid User",
                data: []    
            });

        } else {
            res.status(200).send({
                message: "User deleted",
                data: []
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I implemented my DELETE endpoint for my resetful API as above.
Weird thing is, when I delete it on Postman, it deletes it fine
and it will be gone from the data. But when I try to delete that again,
it gives me the Status 200 with "User deleted" message again.

I am assuming this is becuase mongoose does not error when id is not found when it tries to delete it.

How would I have to adjust it so that it gives me a right message and status response when I try to delete a deleted data?

Comment: Looks like `user.remove`does not error if the user id doesn't exist.  Something in there?

Comment: How would I have to fix it?

Comment: Look at `users` ( it's actually an update response object) when the opertation is performed. It will actually tell you if anything matched or not.

Comment: I am new to this so I am not sure if I am getting your answer correctly, but it is something like check if users is null or not inside the function(err, users) and then give the error message if it is?

Comment: I got it work! Thanks for the advice.